# How to mak a recursive self join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, recursion, view

I'm building a webshop which needs to produce a gatherlist.
The problem is that i have 3 kinds of products and a recursive table (infinite).
namely Products, Option and Category, were category's are the recursive ones.

I'm trying to build a view with the fields `Order.id`, `OrderProduct.product`, `Component.id`.

Here you can see what i've already, however i removed the part of -- by option as it doesn't 'feed' the example.

```
CREATE VIEW `Gatherlist` as
SELECT `O`.`id`, `OP`.`product`, `C`.`id` FROM `Order` `O` -- By Product
LEFT JOIN `OrderProduct` `OP`
    ON `O`.`id` = `OP`.`order`
LEFT JOIN `Product` `P`
    ON `OP`.`product` = `P`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `ProductComponent` `PC`
    ON `P`.`id` = `PC`.`product`
LEFT JOIN `Component` `C`
    ON `PC`.`component` = `C`.`id`
UNION ALL
SELECT `O`.`id`, `OP`.`product`, `C`.`id` FROM `Order` `O` -- By Category
LEFT JOIN `OrderProduct` `OP`
    ON `O`.`id` = `OP`.`order`
LEFT JOIN `Product` `P`
    ON `OP`.`product` = `P`.`id`
-- LEFT JOIN `Category` `PC`
    -- ON `P`.`category` = `PC`.`id`
    -- Here should start a recursive join on Category
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT group_concat(@id :=
            (
                SELECT id
                FROM `Category`
                WHERE parent = @id
                )
            ) AS categoryTemp
        FROM (
            SELECT @id := 1
        ) vars
        STRAIGHT_JOIN
            `Category`
        WHERE @id IS NOT NULL
    ) as `PC` on `P`.`category` = `PC`.`id`
    -- And it will end somewhere again (i hope)
LEFT JOIN `CategoryCompenent` `CC`
    ON `PC`.`id` = `CC`.`category`
LEFT JOIN `Component` `C`
    ON `CC`.`component` = `C`.`id`
ORDER BY `O`.`id`, `OP`.`product`, `C`.`id`
```

My table Category looks like this:

- id - Obvious
- label - id of a name in another table
- parent - the id of the above laying Category

I have found this but could not figure out how to put it in a join (within a view with unions).

```
SELECT  group_concat(@id :=
    (
    SELECT  id
    FROM    comments
    WHERE   parent_id = @id
    )) AS comment
FROM    (
    SELECT  @id := 1
    ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
    comments
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Session variables are black magic in MySQL. Don't use them unless you absolutely have no choice. Do recursion on the client side instead.

Comment: I'm not as allergic to session variables as @Quassnoi, but even I would balk at that. It is generally a very very very bad idea to use the same one across so many different clauses.

Comment: i have read that as well but since i use a view i see no other option than that. (if it can be made to work within a view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real way (at least that I know of) to do a "recursive" join in MySQL. If you have such a table structure, the best solution I know of is using stored procedures to loop through and "collect" related rows and/or build "paths"; unfortunately, you cannot join to the results of a stored procedure, so that usually means having it drop that data into a predetermined temp table to be used after the procedure has executed.

Alternately, you can analyse the recursive table in code to determine its current "depth" in order to compose the query programmatically.

Comment: I got to admit i never looked into stored procedures, and don't know how they work. but from what i find right now it seems it's not allowed to use stored procedures inside a view. Also the depth may vary there is no static depth within them, not now and not in the future, sadly enough.

Comment: Hence programmatically determining the depth every time. And nope, you cannot use a stored procedure in a view, but it can return a result set; Ii a sense behaving similarly to a view, but without the ability to be JOINed, WHEREd, etc.. However, you can reproduce similar functionality (with varying degrees of difficulty) using parameters to the stored procedure.

Comment: @IMarks, also, I've never tried, but it might be possible to use the stored procedure to actually dynamically create (and recreate) the view as needed.